# Maven max attempt to download from a Repository

Tags: maven

it's possible to stop build, whit a failure, when maven try to download for n-times, configured in settings.xml, a different dependency from same private Nexus?

We have an authenticated Nexus, linked whit LDAP.
If user change password, and user forget to change in his own setting.xml, he block his account.

I cannot change any policies.

Thanks for any tricks!

Comment: Technically the build should failed with a 401 Unauthorized if he forget to update his password into his settings.xml. Please make your question more clear I don't have enough information to provide oyu a proper answer

Comment: It failed if maven does not found in local repository the dependencies, but if It found in local repository the build not failed. What I want prevent is to blocking my account, limiting the error during download phase to max 2 attemps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of using the default dependency plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/
You could use https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin

And in the documentation you can find the following

> This plugin has 2 goals:
>   download:artifact
>   Description: This mojo is designed to download a maven artifact from the
>       repository and download them in the specified path. The maven artifact
>       downloaded can also download it's dependency or not, based on a parameter.
>
> retries (Default: 2)
>         How many retries for a download

Comment: Thanks! It's a good solution for "expert" developer! I try to fix Wagon library adding a System.exit (-1) in WagonRepositoryConnector during management of ArtifactTransferException. This is a quick and dirty solution. Maybe, with time, I will produce something more solid